# Nestjs error import "reflect-metadata" Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Right now I'm having a problem. When i add relationship many-to-many it's not working. But before with relation one-to-many.

- error import "reflect-metadata" Cannot use import statement outside a module
- error ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope

[My pull request](https://github.com/duong120798/nest-project/pull/1/files)

**user.entity.ts**

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User implements IUser {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({ length: 25, nullable: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, length: 255 })
  email: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Message, (message) => message.user)
  messages?: Message[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Conversation, (conversations) => conversations.users)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'user_conversation',
    joinColumn: { name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'conversation_id' },
  })
  conversations: Conversation[];
}
```

in file **conversation.entity.ts**

```
@Entity({ name: 'conversations' })
export class Conversation implements IConversation {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'title', nullable: true })
  title: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (users) => users.conversations)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'user_conversation',
    joinColumn: { name: 'conversation_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'user_id' },
  })
  users: User[];
}
```

my error :

```
import "reflect-metadata";
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16) ....
```

When i add *"type": "module"* to package.json have error

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and ....
```

I tried many ways but can't solve it, please help me.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet this comes from the use of `@JoinTable` from `typeorm/browser` [as seen in your Pull Request](https://github.com/duong120798/nest-project/pull/1/files#diff-c6b174724cea2415024927bd1c16f6721a644c3f7505d5b672eeb52956b6532dR13)

Comment: it's working, thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check your imports, it should be `import {...} from 'typeorm'`. Avoid imports  from `'typeorm/browser'`.